# Syntax error when manage.py runserver

Tags: django, python-3.x, web, syntax-error

I am making my first website with Python and django. Everything went well until I got a an error for no obvious reason.

It says syntax error, but I checked with django and I can see no problems.

[image: Screenshot]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Provide the full `urls.py` file in question.

Comment: [link(https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6eb3725cfbc31bf4182552b62a999f58)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an indentation problem? Make sure the indentation is consistent in the file and on that line.

Also post all the `urls.py` code please.

Answer (score 0):

Your `urls.py` is missing a comma

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('personal.urls')) # <-- Missing Here
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Also, be sure that your URLs in `personal.urls` and `blog.urls` end in `$`, as well as `^admin/`. As Alasdair pointed out, **don't** include a `$` in your regexes that have an `include`. That is, `^blog/` remains as is, but any URLs included from `blog.urls` should end with a `$`.

Comment: You shouldn't use a `$` in these URL patterns - they use `include`!